# Is there a better way of shuffling a vector in C++?

Tags: c++

I was making a BlackJack/21 game as I'm learning C++ to give me some experience in actually working on a project. I'm coming from Java, where there's a nice `Collections.shuflfe(...)` feature, but I couldn't find a reliable (and random) solution to achieve a similar result with C++.

I tried the below, and it's working quite well, but I was wondering if there's a much better way to do this, as I feel like I might not need to be using two vectors. However, I can't quite figure out what I could do to replace it, if anything at all. Currently, this is efficient enough for my simple card game, but I want to ask if there's anything I could improve on to make this simpler and/or more efficient for future uses?

```
template <class T> static vector<T> shuffle(vector<T> input) {
    vector<T> values;
    vector<int> indexes;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        indexes.push_back(i);
    }

    //Seed the random number
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    while(!indexes.empty()) {
        //Gets a random index from the currently unused indexes for the input.
        int index = rand() % indexes.size();
        int location = indexes.at(index);

        //Adds the value of the input at the randomly generated location to the new values.
        values.push_back(input.at(location));

        //remove chosen index from the list
        indexes.erase(indexes.begin() + index);
    }

    return values;
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's what I originally wanted to use, but when I try to reference that, it shows that it doesn't exist. Is that new to the most recent versions of C++?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux They actually want to use `std::shuffle`.  `std::random_shuffle` has been removed.

Comment: Oops. It seems [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) is the proper function to use now in modern c++. All overloads of `std::random_shuffle` were removed in c++17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::shuffle` in `<algorithm>` should be what you're looking for. Here's an example of it in use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector {1,2,3,4,5};

  std::random_device rd;
  std::default_random_engine gen(rd);

  std::shuffle (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), gen);

  for (int& x: myvector) std::cout << ' ' << x;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This example is adapted to use vectors from a version found at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/. Checkout the link for more info on `std::shuffle`

Comment: Prefer `std::shuffle` to `std::random_shuffle`.  The later was removed in C++17

Comment: [Alternative (more detailed but generally harder to read as a result) documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: OP has stated in a comment to the question that his/her version of c++ does not have a `std::random_shuffle`. They must be using c++17 where this function does not exist.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize it was out of date. Fixed now

Comment: Where possible, use `std::random_device` to seed the RNG. Time is too predictable. Here it likely doesn't matter, but when it does matter... Hooo boy! It matters a lot.

Comment: @user4581301 what's the difference in using current time vs `std::random_device`? Would you care to elaborate why `std::random_device` is better?

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, edited the answer, even if it doesn't matter much here its much easier to read.

Comment: @Mr_Rhetorical `random_device` is intended to provide a highly random seed to random number generators. With a predictable seed, an attacker can use their knowledge of the seed and the algorithm used to generate the random numbers to predict the numbers. This makes for a very boring, if profitable, game of online poker, an empty bank account, or Top Secret documents that can be read with the ease of a comic book. [Documentation for `random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device). Heed the warning that it doesn't work in MinGW.

Comment: `random_device` is a double edge sword. It's designed to represent the best source of randomness available on the system but it's also not *required* to be highly random. So you get some implementations like MinGW's where it's not random at all (and this is conformant but discouraged).

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, there's a `shuffle` function in the standard libraries... but if you're curious, in-place shuffle is fairly easy to implement.

```
template<typename T, typename E>
void shuffle(std::vector<T> & items, E & engine)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < items.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(i, items.size() - 1);
        int iTarget = dist(engine);
        std::swap(items[i], items[iTarget]);
    }
}
```

It works like this:

- We divide the vector into **shuffled** and **unshuffled** portions, with `i` being the index of the first unshuffled item.
- We start with `i = 0`: the **shuffled** portion is empty, and the **unshuffled** portion comprises the whole vector.
- While the **unshuffled** portion isn't empty, we're going to move items out of it and into the **shuffled** portion.

  - We pick a **random index in the unshuffled range** (between `i` and the end of the vector) and designate it as the "target" item.
  - We take the first unshuffled item (`items[i]`) and swap it with the target.
  - The target (now at position `i`) is considered **shuffled**. We increment `i`, meaning that the **shuffled** portion grew and the **unshuffled** portion shrank.

Does this `shuffle` actually produce a uniform distribution? See for yourself, with a simple test program:

```
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());

    static const int N_TEST_CASES = 200000;
    static const int N_ITEMS = 10;

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > distributions;
    distributions.resize(N_ITEMS);
    for (int i = 0; i < N_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        distributions[i].resize(N_ITEMS);
        for (int j = 0; j < N_ITEMS; j++)
            distributions[i][j] = 0;
    }

    for (int iTestCase = 0; iTestCase < N_TEST_CASES; iTestCase++)
    {
        std::vector<int> items;
        items.resize(N_ITEMS);
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ITEMS; i++)
            items[i] = i;

        shuffle(items, engine);

        for (int iItem = 0; iItem < N_ITEMS; iItem++)
            for (unsigned iPosition = 0; iPosition < items.size(); iPosition++)
                if (items[iPosition] == iItem)
                    distributions[iItem][iPosition]++;
    }

    for (int iItem = 0; iItem < N_ITEMS; iItem++)
    {
        std::cout << "Item " << iItem << ":\n";
        for (unsigned iPosition = 0; iPosition < distributions[iItem].size(); iPosition++)
            std::cout << "  Position #" << iPosition << ": " << (float)distributions[iItem][iPosition] / (float)N_TEST_CASES << "\n";

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 Edited to use the shiny new `<random>` header.